# How to make two factor authentication token expire after single use

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, two-factor-authentication

I implemented two factor authentication but by following this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity

I want to make the code expire after single use.

Right now, user receives the same code during the expiration time (which is set to 5 minutes) completes. Is there a way to make the code single use? I couldn't find anything on this subject.

Answer (score 5):

There is a note in the [tutorial that you linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity) that says:

> The 2FA codes are generated using [Time-based One-time Password Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) and codes are valid for six minutes. If you take more than six minutes to enter the code, you'll get an Invalid code error message.

So, using this method, you cannot make the code expire after user.

You could, as an addition, keep a store of codes that have been used and check against that store before validating the code. You could allow the codes to expire out of that store after 6 minutes, which is their natural expiry time, but in the meantime use them to reject a second authentication.

Alternatively, you can choose to avoid the TOTP method and generate a random code that you store against your user before you send the SMS or email. Then you can check against that code when the user authenticates with it and delete or invalidate the code at that point. Using TOTP means that you could extend this 2FA to use an authenticator app based flow for the authentication too, which is more secure than SMS or email.

Answer (score 3):

AspNetIdentity does not automatically invalidate used second factor codes, a code is always valid for a six minute window, but there is a workaround for this.

One of the inputs to the token generator is the `SecurityStamp`, which is stored as part of the user account. Token providers that extend the `TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider`, like for example the `EmailTokenProvider`, will use the security stamp when they generate and validate a second factor code.

Thus, you can invalidate all issued tokens by changing the security stamp by calling `UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId)` after a successful two factor authentication.

There is a side effect that may not be desirable, being that other sessions will get logged out when the security stamp changes.

In the `ApplicationSignInManager` class, you can override `TwoFactorSignInAsync` and make the call there:
(Note: This is taken from [AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity), if you are using a different package, make sure to take `TwoFactorSignInAsync` from that instead and modify it accordingly.)

```cs
public override async Task<SignInStatus> TwoFactorSignInAsync(string provider, string code, bool isPersistent, bool rememberBrowser)
{
    var userId = await GetVerifiedUserIdAsync().WithCurrentCulture();
    if (userId == null)
    {
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
    }
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).WithCurrentCulture();
    if (user == null)
    {
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
    }
    if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture())
    {
        return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
    }
    if (await UserManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, provider, code).WithCurrentCulture())
    {
        // When token is verified correctly, clear the access failed count used for lockout
        await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture();

        // Update the security stamp in order to invalidate all issued two factor tokens.
        await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);

        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, rememberBrowser).WithCurrentCulture();
        return SignInStatus.Success;
    }
    // If the token is incorrect, record the failure which also may cause the user to be locked out
    await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture();
    return SignInStatus.Failure;
}
```

If you want only the latest issued code to be valid, you should make the call to `UpdateSecurityStampAsync` also before any new code is generated.

Comment: While this works, there is a side effect that may not be desirable being that other sessions will get logged out when the security stamp changes.