# Reason to genarate the Same 2FA(Email/SMS) OTP multiple times in ASP.net identity core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, two-factor-authentication

In ASP.net core identity application, I am getting the same 2FA(Email/SMs) OTP multiple times within a short time period. Please note that i am not talking about 2FA via authenticator app.

I am using following code to generate the OTP. I am using asp.net core 3.1 identity

```
_userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Email")
```

What is the default 2FA OTP time period which is generating the same 2FA OTP?

Also is there a way to configure that time period in the application?

Comment: It's a time based totp code, not a one time pad. You'd probably have to replace the token provider completely to tweak how it works.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyLakeman, Do you know the default time period according to the TOTP algorithm? Our QA is asking for the value

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/EmailTokenProvider.cs ends up here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs#L14

Comment: Also see [How to make two factor authentication token expire after single use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186325/).

Comment: Thanks all, I found the default time period which is generating same OTP is around 90 seconds and the codes generating via TOTP are valid for 6 minutes.  According to the URL mentioned on @MarkG's comment we can expire the code after a single use.